# How to set the sidebar width for Nebular if I have two sidebars in my layout?

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

So I have two sidebars (tagged left and right) in my page layout as seen in the code snippet below. I used the custom theme approach and used the `sidebar-width: 400px,` property to set the sidebar width. What this does is set both the sidebar width to 400px. How do I make the right sidebar 700px?
Is there a way to target the sidebar width by ID to achieve this?

```
<nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-header>header</nb-layout-header>
    <nb-sidebar left state="collapsed" tag="left" >
    </nb-sidebar>
    <nb-sidebar right state="collapsed" tag="right">
    </nb-sidebar>
    <nb-layout-column>content</nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the styles by assigning new values for their theme [css variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp), and this can be set according to the selector (id is one of them)

looking at [nebular sidebar theme](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/sidebar/theme#nbsidebarcomponent) you can find all the variables, the one you are looking for here is `sidebar-width`

so your style can be something like this

```
nb-sidebar[left]{
--sidebar-width: 400px;
}
nb-sidebar[right]{
--sidebar-width: 700px;
}
```